# Application Crash when using android.widget.Button class as a global variable

Tags: android

I can't for the life of me figure this out, and I've searched as thoroughly as I can.

I've got a block of code like so:

```
    public class TwoPlayerGame extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);                    
}



public GameStuff game = new GameStuff();
public Player playerOne = new Player();
public Player playerTwo = new Player();

public Player[] players = {playerOne, playerTwo};

public Button cardOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card1);
public Button cardTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card2);
public Button cardThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card3);
public Button cardFour=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card4);
public Button cardFive=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card5);

public Button[] buttons={cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree, cardFour, cardFive};

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


    for(int i=0; i<=1; i++){
        dealCards(players[i]);
    }



    for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
        buttons[i].setText(playerOne.cardsInHand[i]);
    }


}


}
```

As written this will crash as soon as the Activity starts (it'll even crash if I change the onStart override into a new method altogether). If I move all the Button declarations into the onStart method, everything works fine, but then they won't be global. If I move them into onCreate, they won't be global, according to Eclipse, and I get errors that won't let me compile.

All the other global variables work fine where they are, and I need the buttons to be global so I don't have to keep re-declaring them in new methods.

Am I overlooking something blindingly obvious (probably)? And what is it?

Comment: You can declare your Buttons global but do not call findViewById, or assign them any values, before setContentView has been called.

Comment: I realise I'm shouting in the forest and there is no-one to listen, but can we please start a campaign to stop calling class level fields (variables) "globals".  They are not.  There, I feel better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    public class TwoPlayerGame extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        cardOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card1);
        cardTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card2);
        cardThree=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card3);
        cardFour=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card4);
        cardFive=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card5);

    }


public GameStuff game = new GameStuff();
public Player playerOne = new Player();
public Player playerTwo = new Player();

public Player[] players = {playerOne, playerTwo};

public Button cardOne;
public Button cardTwo;
public Button cardThree;
public Button cardFour;
public Button cardFive;

public Button[] buttons={cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree, cardFour, cardFive};

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


    for(int i=0; i<=1; i++){
        dealCards(players[i]);
    }



    for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
        buttons[i].setText(playerOne.cardsInHand[i]);
    }


}


}
```

you can not get the `Buttons` from the `findViewById` before calling `setContentView`. It is impossible.

Comment: I tried exactly this and it still crashes. I even tried moving the findViewByIds into onStart, and it crashes.

Comment: what `stack trace` says? Any log in logcat.. also move `buttons={cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree, cardFour, cardFive};` after initializing  all the buttons.

Comment: I'm still pretty new at this, so I'm not sure how to get a `stack trace` in Eclipse. If I make the `buttons` array local, it works, but I can't declare `public Button[] buttons;` and then move `buttons={cardOne...}` into onCreate or onStart without getting an 'Array constants can only be used in initializers' error.

Comment: Actually, I've thought of a way to restructure my methods so I shouldn't need the array to be global. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should realize that lines

```
public Button cardOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.card1);
... and others
```

are called when the class is created. But this is before onCreate is called. It crashes because to use findViewById you need to first call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
```

but its actually called after the initialization of the class and therefore after findViewById calls.